# Disable autofill for html input email field

Tags: html, safari, autofill, input-field

I have the following html code:

```
<input autocomplete="off" placeholder="Mail">
```

When I open this in Apples Safari browser and click on the input field, a dropdown list appears, showing my e-mail addresses as suggestions for autofill.

It looks like this:

[image]

How can I prevent Safari from showing it?

(Maybe the same behavior occurs in other browsers, but I wasn't able to test it. Also, Safari is the main target audience.)

Comment: Did you try `autocomplete="new-password"`?

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly Yes, I didn’t. Didn’t change anything. Still the same.

Comment: try <form autocomplete="off"> for form only

Comment: @hashemsheikhypour Doesn't change anything, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

To disable autocompletion in forms, you can set the autocomplete attribute to "off":

```
autocomplete="off"

autocomplete="false" or autocomplete="new-password"
```

You can do this either for an entire form, or for specific input elements in a form:

```
<form method="post" action="/form" autocomplete="off">
[…]
</form>
```

or

```
<input role="presentation" autocomplete="off" />
```

or Try add some CSS for Input

```
input::-webkit-contacts-auto-fill-button, 
input::-webkit-credentials-auto-fill-button {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
}
```

**But I think this is the case for Chrome and Mozilla, not Safari**

for just you in safari can disable from setting but ot for User  :

```
In macOS, choose Safari > Preferences > AutoFill.
```

Comment: other way can disable attribute with js  $('.inputClass').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

Comment: It's still the same. I need this to work for Safari. I cannot ask all my users to disable `Safari > Preferences > AutoFill`. So this isn't a solution either.

Comment: Yes, it is not possible to request this from users, what did you test through JS and deactivation?

Comment: I edited the answer. Please try the added solution or hide Att like this stackoverflow.com/a/39885072/8577321